# Trying to understand the behavior of a very simple piece of python code: return [x[0] for x in y]

Tags: python, syntax, for-loop, return-value

I thought (and still Contino not understand why the difference) this code:

```
def categories(self):
    cur=self.con.execute('select category from cc');
    for d in cur:
        return d[0]
```

was equivalent to this other:

```
def categories(self):
    cur=self.con.execute('select category from cc');
    return [d[0] for d in cur]
```

But when I replace one by another in my code I got an error in other place of the code:

```
  File "C:\Users\CG\Desktop\Google Drive\Sci&Tech\projects\naivebayes\main.py", line 226, in post
    spam_result = nb.classify(given_sentence)
  File "C:\Users\CG\Desktop\Google Drive\Sci&Tech\projects\naivebayes\main.py", line 204, in classify
    if cat==best: continue
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'best' referenced before assignment
```

Why this happen? Why the two piece of code aren't equivalent?

Entire code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3

import USSSALoader

import random

from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite

import re

import math

def getfeatures(doc):
  splitter=re.compile('\\W*')
  # Split the words by non-alpha characters
  words=[s.lower() for s in splitter.split(doc)
          if len(s)>2 and len(s)<20]
  # Return the unique set of words only
#  return dict([(w,1) for w in words]).iteritems()
  return dict([(w,1) for w in words])


class classifier:
  def __init__(self,getfeatures, filename=None):
    # Counts of feature/category combinations
    self.fc={}
    # Counts of documents in each category
    self.cc={}
    self.getfeatures=getfeatures

#  def setdb(self,dbfile):
    self.con=sqlite.connect('db_file')
#    self.con=sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    self.con.execute('create table if not exists fc(feature,category,count)')
    self.con.execute('create table if not exists cc(category,count)')

  def incf(self,f,cat):
    count=self.fcount(f,cat)
    if count==0:
      self.con.execute("insert into fc values ('%s','%s',1)" % (f,cat))
    else:
      self.con.execute(
        "update fc set count=%d where feature='%s' and category='%s'"
        % (count+1,f,cat))

  def fcount(self,f,cat):
    res=self.con.execute(
      'select count from fc where feature="%s" and category="%s"'
      %(f,cat)).fetchone()
    if res==None: return 0
    else: return float(res[0])

  def incc(self,cat):
    count=self.catcount(cat)
    if count==0:
      self.con.execute("insert into cc values ('%s',1)" % (cat))
    else:
      self.con.execute("update cc set count=%d where category='%s'"
                       % (count+1,cat))

  def catcount(self,cat):
    res=self.con.execute('select count from cc where category="%s"'
                         %(cat)).fetchone()
    if res==None: return 0
    else: return float(res[0])

  def categories(self):
    cur=self.con.execute('select category from cc');
#    return [d[0] for d in cur]
    for d in cur:
 #       print "d =", d
  #      print "d[0] =", d[0]
        return d[0]

  def totalcount(self):
    res=self.con.execute('select sum(count) from cc').fetchone();
    if res==None: return 0
    print "res=self.con.execute('select * FROM cc').fetchall(); = ", self.con.execute('select * FROM cc').fetchall();
    print 'res sum(count) = ', res
    print 'res[0] = ', res[0]
    return res[0]

  def train(self,item,cat):
    features=self.getfeatures(item)
    # Increment the count for every feature with this category
    for f in features:
##    for f in features:
      self.incf(f,cat)
    # Increment the count for this category
    self.incc(cat)
    self.con.commit()

  def fprob(self,f,cat):
    if self.catcount(cat)==0: return 0
    # The total number of times this feature appeared in this
    # category divided by the total number of items in this category
    return self.fcount(f,cat)/self.catcount(cat)

  def weightedprob(self,f,cat,prf,weight=1.0,ap=0.5):
    # Calculate current probability
    basicprob=prf(f,cat)
    # Count the number of times this feature has appeared in
    # all categories
    totals=sum([self.fcount(f,c) for c in self.categories()])
    # Calculate the weighted average
    bp=((weight*ap)+(totals*basicprob))/(weight+totals)
    return bp

class naivebayes(classifier):

  def __init__(self,getfeatures):
    classifier.__init__(self, getfeatures)
    self.thresholds={}

  def docprob(self,item,cat):
    features=self.getfeatures(item)
    # Multiply the probabilities of all the features together
    p=1
    for f in features: p*=self.weightedprob(f,cat,self.fprob)
    return p

  def prob(self,item,cat):
    catprob=self.catcount(cat)/self.totalcount()
    docprob=self.docprob(item,cat)
    return docprob*catprob

  def setthreshold(self,cat,t):
    self.thresholds[cat]=t

  def getthreshold(self,cat):
    if cat not in self.thresholds: return 1.0
    return self.thresholds[cat]

  def classify(self,item,default=None):
    probs={}
    # Find the category with the highest probability
    max=0.0
    for cat in self.categories():
      probs[cat]=self.prob(item,cat)
      if probs[cat]>max:
        max=probs[cat]
        best=cat

    # Make sure the probability exceeds threshold*next best
    for cat in probs:
      if cat==best: continue
      if probs[cat]*self.getthreshold(best)>probs[best]: return default
    return best

def sampletrain(cl):
  cl.train('Nobody owns the water.','good')
  cl.train('the quick rabbit jumps fences','good')
  cl.train('buy pharmaceuticals now','bad')
  cl.train('make quick money at the online casino','bad')
  cl.train('the quick brown fox jumps','good')


nb = naivebayes(getfeatures)

sampletrain(nb)


doc_test = "buy pharmaceuticals now or earn money at the online casino"

print ('\ndoc_test is classified as %s'%nb.classify(doc_test))
```

Comment: your error has nothing to do with the snippets you posted. they are different because in the first it will return the 0th element of the first item in the list in the second it will return a list of all the 0th elements in the list

Comment: I get the feeling that the first statement should be `yield` and not `return` (as you would only ever get one row back even if multiple rows were returned).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function only returns once.

When you see

```
for d in cur:
    return d[0]
```

the loop returns during the first iteration.

But this [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
return [d[0] for d in cur]
```

loops over every item in `cur` to create a list and then returns the result.

Comment: Thanks, Steven. I didn't know the behavior of `[d[0] for d in cur]`. I didn't know it was creating a list. Now I fixed my code. Thanks again!

Comment: @Pythonista'sApprentice: Just one additional tip. This list comprehension is part of larger family of comprehensions (and generators). In similar way you can use set comprehension (`{i ** 2 for i in range(10)}`) to build a `set`, dictionary comprehension (`{i: i ** 2 for i in range(10)}`) to build a `dict`, or generator expression (`(i ** 2 for i in range(10))`) to build a `generator` object. The last one is special, as it can be iterated over only once ([see here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)) and the parentheses can be omitted if it is the only argument passed to some callable.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Steven Rumbalksi's answer, the following code:

```
dList = []
for d in cur:
    dList.append(d[0])
return dList
```

would be equivalent to:

```
return [d[0] for d in cur]
```

[List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are really powerful like that, but they can be excessively dense ways of expressing the ideas, especially when you start nesting them, which leads to difficulty reading and debugging code.

Answer (score 1):

i think you may be confusing a regular function for a generator, change

```
for d in cur:
    return d[0]
```

to

```
for d in cur:
    yield d[0]
```

to return an iterable